# How to send an agent to a room once it becomes available in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic, agent

I am creating a simulation of a clinic and I currently have patients in a waiting room being sent to an exam room once their wait time is over in the delay block. However, rooms often become available prior to the agent's wait time being finished. How can I trigger the agent movement out of the delay block and to an available room?

Comment: Patients should wait in a queue and with a seize or service block next to it. They will only exit the queue if they can seize a resource, which in your case would be a room. Check this model in the cloud or in your help -> example models, it is exactly what you need - https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/0c41592c-96d8-4824-b816-c89eccfd79db?mode=SETTINGS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need to do is for your rooms that are available to be defined as resources, so instead of a delay time you have a seize block that takes the room as a resource. With a seize block, the agents will wait as long as needed until a room is available.

Now, if you need the patient to wait anyways for a certain period of time, then you can add a delay after the seize block in order to wait that time before moving into the room... but the room will already be reserved to that patient with the seize.

Comment: Thanks Felipe. The rooms are defined as resources and are being seized using seize blocks. The issue is that my patients are waiting in a delay block for a triangularly defined time length that sometimes is too long in comparison to when a room becomes free. I believe I can better frame my question by asking which block I should use to hold my waiting patients before a room becomes free.

Comment: this doesn't make sense... why do you want to hold the patient in the waiting room if the room is free... and if you don't want to do that, why are you using a delay at all

Comment: If all rooms are occupied, my patients wait. If a room is not occupied, they wait in the delay block until their time is up. As a beginner with AnyLogic, I would like to know if I can omit the delay block altogether and have the patients wait in the seize block until a room becomes free.

Comment: yes throw that delay to the trash... its completely useless.... now the question... if the time is up and the rooms are still occupied... what do you want the patient to do? Go home?

Answer (score 1):

Create an event that runs every second to check if there is available room. If the condition is satisfied, remove the first agent from the `Delay` block with the command `myDelay.remove(myDelay.get(0))`.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. So within the event block, the trigger type will be Condition with said condition that you provided? Or does the command go in the delay block with another trigger type in the event?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how your model is exactly built. But assuming you have a resource called `room` with capacity `10`, you can say `if (room.busy()<10) { myDelay.remove(myDelay.get(0)) }`

Comment: Correct I do have said resource. So this command would go in the delay block 'On remove' I am assuming?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you need to assign something for those agents, you need to use the 'On remove' field.

Comment: I have found that without adding an event and reducing the Delay wait time to 1 second, agents are held in the next block which is a Seize Room block, but remain in the waiting area. Virtually, this solves the problem. However, I would like to be thorough and ask how I should set up the event block.